Can i identify transaction error in getSignaturesForAddress method
i am working with @solana/web3.js. I want to make archive about an address.
When i call this method: getSignaturesForAddress, can i identify its an error transaction or not without calling the getParsedTransactions/getTransactions?

getSignaturesForAddress will actually give you the error information about transactions! It'll be in the "err" field. Here's an example on the SPL Token program:
jon@is-that-rye~/s/s/s/s/js> curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
                               {
                                 "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                                 "id": 1,
                                 "method": "getSignaturesForAddress",
                                 "params": [
                                   "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
                                   {
                                     "limit": 100
                                   }
                                 ]
                               }
                             '
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"blockTime":1725884002,"confirmationStatus":"finalized","err":{"InstructionError":[2,{"Custom":30}]},"memo":null,"signature":"3w5bFKo4epbz1ZyeGf7USQXKah3LE6kDDLoDKLWXEgkW1LtuK3dUexPvbeYr8LfEV3uqvM8gwgSghiqBkXrrBWpF","slot":288760405},
...
]

More information at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getsignaturesforaddress
